# Content type edit page redirect to user edit page

Tags: php, redirect, drupal-7

I have a large multilingual website.

My problem is that when I try to edit the content type from `/admin/structure/types/article` with admin account page is redirected to `/user/xxx/edit` page. I could not find a way to check from which page it is redirecting. I have checked the permission of my user and all is OK.

Is there any way or a drupal module which can help me to find out the origin of the wrong redirection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but I personally would do the following: go to the [node_page_edit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_page_edit/7) function and place the following code right in the beginning:

```
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
exit;
```

Then you can figure out the sequence of events that led to that page.

PS: use *print_r*, *dpm* or whatever you want. I like *var_dump* ;)